# Error: A const field of a reference type other than string can only be initialized with null

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

The error is simple but i wont be able to solve this i hope u guys help me in this

This is my aspx page code

```
 <asp:TreeView ID="PictureTree" runat="server" ShowLines="True">
                    <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Bold="True" />
                    <NodeStyle ImageUrl="~/Images/Folder.jpg" />
                </asp:TreeView>

            </td>
            <td style="width:auto;text-align:center;" valign="top">
                <asp:DataList ID="PicturesInFolder" runat="server" Width="100%" CellPadding="5">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <h3><asp:Label runat="server" ID="FileNameLabel" Text='<%# System.IO.Path.GetFilenameWithoutExtension(Eval("Name")) %>'></asp:Label></h3>

                        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="Picture" ImageUrl='<%# PictureTree.SelectedValue & Eval("Name").ToString() %>' />
                        <br /><br />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#E0E0E0" />
                </asp:DataList>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="NoPicturesInFolderMessage" Font-Italic="True" Visible="False" EnableViewState="False">
                    There are no pictures in the selected folder...
                </asp:Label>
```

This is my .cs code

```
private const object VirtualImageRoot = "~/Images/Departments/";


protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // On the first page visit, populate the photo tree and select the root node
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        PopulateTree();
        PictureTree.Nodes[0].Select();
        PictureTree_SelectedNodeChanged(PictureTree, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

private void PopulateTree()
{
    // Populate the tree based on the subfolders of the specified VirtualImageRoot
    DirectoryInfo rootFolder = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(VirtualImageRoot));
    TreeNode root = AddNodeAndDescendents(rootFolder, null);
    // Add the root to the TreeView
    PictureTree.Nodes.Add(root);
}

private TreeNode AddNodeAndDescendents(DirectoryInfo folder, TreeNode parentNode)
{
    // Add the TreeNode, displaying the folder's name and storing the full path to the folder as the value...
    string virtualFolderPath;
    if ((parentNode == null))
    {
        virtualFolderPath = VirtualImageRoot;
    }
    else
    {
        virtualFolderPath = (parentNode.Value
                    + (folder.Name + "/"));
    }
    TreeNode node = new TreeNode(folder.Name, virtualFolderPath);
    // Recurse through this folder's subfolders
    DirectoryInfo[] subFolders = folder.GetDirectories();
    foreach (DirectoryInfo subFolder in subFolders)
    {
        TreeNode child = AddNodeAndDescendents(subFolder, node);
        node.ChildNodes.Add(child);
    }
    return node;
    // Return the new TreeNode
}

protected void PictureTree_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Refresh the DataList whenever a new node is selected
    DisplayPicturesInFolder(PictureTree.SelectedValue);
}

private void DisplayPicturesInFolder(string virtualFolderPath)
{
    // Security check: make sure folderPath starts with VirtualImageRoot and doesn't include any ".."
    if ((!virtualFolderPath.StartsWith(VirtualImageRoot)
                || (virtualFolderPath.IndexOf("..") >= 0)))
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Attempting to view a folder outside of the public image folder!");
    }
    // Get information about the files in the specified folder
    DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(virtualFolderPath));
    FileInfo[] fileList = folder.GetFiles();
    PicturesInFolder.DataSource = fileList;
    PicturesInFolder.DataBind();
    // If there are no pictures in the folder, display the NoPicturesInFolderMessage Label
    PicturesInFolder.Visible = (PicturesInFolder.Items.Count > 0);
    NoPicturesInFolderMessage.Visible = !PicturesInFolder.Visible;
}
}
```

i got error in private const object VirtualImageRoot = "~/Images/Departments/";

That VirtualImageRoot is an object A const field of a reference type other than string can only be initialized with null

how can i solve this thank in advance

Comment: Why is it not a String?

Comment: what i need is to show images from sub-folder of Images/Departmentfolder through datalist some give me this solution but its in vb when i convert it into c# i found this solution it work in vb but not in c#

Comment: view DisplayPicturesInFolder function you will get to know

Comment: Marc is right, there is no reason this should not be a `String`.

Answer (score 15):

`const` supports very few types; if yours isn't one of them, then ***in the general case*** you should use `static readonly` instead:

```
private static readonly object VirtualImageRoot = "~/Images/Departments/";
```

However, it is **very** unclear why this isn't a `string` in your case:

```
private const string VirtualImageRoot = "~/Images/Departments/";
```

Comment: i edit my question please have a look at it when i use your code i got this Error 4 Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Comment: Where would you use an & with a pair of strings?

Comment: @amitesh `+` is `string.Concat`, not `&` - unless you are in VB

Comment: @Marc actually i ask a question and some reply me in vb and when i change my code in c# i got this error i guess the problem is in this line <asp:Image runat="server" ID="Picture" ImageUrl='<%# PictureTree.SelectedValue & Eval("Name").ToString() %>' />

Comment: @amitesh then you need to figure out which language you are coding in, and adjust accordingly

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks marck but the thing is that when i run my code using + in aspx page i can won't be able to view my images in the folders